# The register button is giving me authentication failed, how can i fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The register button is not functioning correctly, It gives me authentication failed toast. it seems like my strings for a create a user with email and password are correct but it still wont work.

What can I do? please help if you can.

Java File:

```
package com.example.ahmadsapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText ETname, ETgmail, ETpassword;
    Button register,Bdateofbirth;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        sp = getSharedPreferences("detail", 0);
        String userdfn = sp.getString("firstname", null);
        String userdgamil = sp.getString("gmail", null);
        String userduser = sp.getString("user", null);
        String userdpass = sp.getString("password", null);

        ETname= findViewById(R.id.ETsignupname);
        ETgmail = findViewById(R.id.ETsignupgmail);
        ETpassword = findViewById(R.id.ETsignuppassword);
        register = findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);
        Bdateofbirth = findViewById(R.id.Bdateofbirth);




        register.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == register) {
            register(ETgmail.getText().toString(), ETpassword.getText().toString());
        }

        if (view == Bdateofbirth) {
            dialogDOB();
        }

    }





     private void register(String User, String Password) {
    
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(User, Password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    
                                addClassToFirebase();
    
                                Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("etsufn", ETname.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
    
    
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Authintication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
    
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
    
        }
    
        private void addClassToFirebase() {
            String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
            User u = new User(uid, ETname.getText().toString(), ETgmail.getText().toString(), ETpassword.getText().toString(), Bdateofbirth.getText().toString(), "");
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").push();
            u.key = databaseReference.getKey();
            databaseReference.setValue(u);
        }
        private void dialogDOB(){
    
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int y = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(signup.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    i1=i1+1;
                    String date = i + "/" + i1 + "/" + i2;
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Bdateofbirth.setText(date);
                }
            }, d, m, y);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    
    
    }
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".signup"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to the signup page"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/TVsignup"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="name"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ETsignupname"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="G-Mail"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ETsignupgmail"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ETsignuppassword"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Bdateofbirth"
        android:text="Date of birth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Register"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/signupbutton"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

the strings I filled in:

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d29O.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a task fails, it contains an exception that explains the reason of the failure. Log this reason to know more about the cause of the problem:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

        addClassToFirebase();

        Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("etsufn", ETname.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);


    } else {
        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
        Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Authintication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("AUTH", "Authentication failed", task.getException()); // 
    }
```

Also see the reference documentation for the [`Task` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task).

Comment: 2the presented exception: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]

Comment: Well, that's the root cause of the problem then. Did you search for the exception already?